# MySQL - Change index column VARCHAR length?

Tags: mysql, indexing, key, varchar, maxlength

I currently have a table with an index column the unique index column "name". Currently the column "name" is a varchar with length 25. I would like to increase this to 50. I'm attempting to use

```
alter table `meal_prices` modify `name` varchar(50);
```

to do this. However, this doesn't seem to affect the column. I have a feeling this isn't working because the column is an index column, but I'm not sure. Any suggestions? Thank you much.

Comment: Does it throw an error?  Or just do nothing?

Comment: As far as I can tell it just does nothing. I'm running it through HeidiSQL Portable. But Heidi would usually show me any errors if they happen and none appear.

Comment: It looks like it should work.  Are you sure it didn't change the data type?  If you run `show create table TABLENAME`, it shows no change to the data type?

Comment: Ah however, it just made sense to then change the length through Heidi itself. Doing this, Heidi prints the code it uses which is `ALTER TABLE 'meal_prices'  CHANGE COLUMN 'name' 'name' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL AFTER 'the_column_before_name';`. This appears to work and I will just use this instead. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: CHANGE COLUMN and MODIFY COLUMN do the same. Both variants should work.

Comment: @Tom: My mistake, I just needed the `show create table TABLENAME` at the end to see the correctly updated data. Feel free to post that as the answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `show create table TABLENAME` afterwards to verify the data type has changed.